# Keep zero after Hexdecimal conversion in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a very simple script in bash:

```
for i in {000..1024} ; do 
     echo $i ; 
     echo "obase=16; $i" | bc
done
```

I want to print all numbers with minimum three digits as 000, 001, 002 .. until 099. With integer numbers it works good, but after `obase = 16; $ i '| bc`s number return with one or two digits.

How can I solve it in the easiest way?

Comment: What do you mean by `minimum three digits`? Can you show a proper expected output?

Comment: 001, 002, 003, 004.... 00A, 00B or 010, 011, 012, 01A, 01A until 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `printf` to format the number, for example:

```
for i in {0..1024} ; do 
     echo $i
     printf '%03X\n' $i
done
```

Or `j=$(printf '%03X' $i)` and then `echo $j`.

For more on formatting check the *Format strings* subsection of [*Syntax* section here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf#syntax).

Comment: `printf` implements an implicit loop: `printf '%03X\n' {0..1024}`.

Comment: @chepner: Neat! However some clarification: the sh/bash is the one that does the expansion, try `echo {1..3}` or `ls {1..3}` and printf accepts multiple parameters, like `printf '%03X\n' 1 2 3` and loops the pattern until no more params found, and it works with more than one format string, like `printf '%03X-%03X\n' 1 2 3 4 5 6`.

Comment: Right; if `printf` receives more arguments than it needs to fill its format specification, it repeats the specification until all arguments are consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's "easiest", but generally printf is good for formatting issues.  eg

```
printf "%03s\n" "$(echo "obase=16; $i" | bc)"
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it doesn't work. Still print 1,2,3,4 not 001, 002...

Comment: @Aso Strife That's odd.  Which platform?

Comment: why are you echoing and piping

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ubuntu, latest version

Comment: @123 Merely duplicating the original question to demonstrate how to incorporate `printf`.  With this particular problem, one would normally just use a `%03x` specifier, but this is a general form for formatting a string.

Comment: @123 I disagree with your description.  It is always best to provide the simplest, clearest solution.  In this case, I believe that means minimizing the changes.

Comment: This is neither clearer nor simpler than the other answer, which is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @AsoStrife Ah.  I am probably using the bash builtin for printf.  Another bashism reaches out to inflict pain on the unsuspecting!

Comment: Using '%x' is the correct way to produce hex output, but it does not solve the general problem of formatting a string.